# Fancybox and YouTube

Tags: youtube, fancybox

I've been searching here for an answer, tried quite a few suggestions, but am still striking out.

I have Fancybox set to display YouTube videos with thumbnails on my site. It had been working without any issues for a while, but now for some reason the videos do not come up in the Fancybox overlay, only the browser window, full-size.

The jquery I've been using is:

```
    <!-- Grab Google CDN's jQuery, fall back to local if offline -->

   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

   <!-- FancyBox -->

   <script src="js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
   <script src="js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js"></script>
   <script src="js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js"></script>
   <script src="js/fancybox/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js"></script>
   <script src="js/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".various").fancybox({
                                              'padding' : 0,
                                              'type' : 'iframe',
                maxWidth    : 800,
                maxHeight   : 600,
                fitToView   : false,
                width       : '70%',
                height      : '70%',
                autoSize    : false,
                closeClick  : false,
                openEffect  : 'elastic',
                closeEffect: 'none'
            });
        });
    </script>
```

The html is set up like this:

```
<a class="various fancybox.iframe" title="Popular Mechanics Show" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Z0Hc272S2mk"><img src="images/video/popmech.jpg"></a>
```

Here is the video page: http://mykelhawke.com/video

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Update: I finally figured out the problem, not Fancybox or YouTube.  It was a noConflict.  I removed it and moved the other jquery code that was not working further down, all good!